# Checking data type of variable derived from user input

Tags: stata

I have the following block of code that I thought should be able to classify a user's input's data type in a Stata .do file:

```
capture program drop smth  
program define smth
di "Enter smth: " _request(smth1)
local type = substr("`: type $smth1 '", 1, 3)
if "`type'" == "str" {
di "It is a string!"
} 
else if "`type'" == "flo" {
di "It is a float!"
} 
else if "`type'" == "int" {
di "It is an integer!"
}
else {
di "it is not a string, float nor integer!"
}
end
```

However, when I executed the .do file (trialscript is the name of the .do file) in a Stata command prompt with the user input, "hello", I encountered the following error:

```
. do trialscript

. capture program drop smth       

. program define smth
  1. di "Enter smth: " _request(smth1)
  2. local type = substr("`: type $smth1 '", 1, 3)
  3. if "`type'" == "str" {
  4. di "It is a string!"
  5. } 
  6. else if "`type'" == "flo" {
  7. di "It is a float!"
  8. } 
  9. else if "`type'" == "int" {
 10. di "It is an integer!"
 11. }
 12. else {
 13. di "it is not a string, float nor integer!"
 14. }
 15. end

.  
. 
end of do-file

. smth
Enter smth: . hello
no variables defined
it is not a string, float nor integer!
```

Answer (score 1):

What the user enters given your code is put into a global macro, which is not a variable in Stata's sense, as a variable is (only) a column of data in a dataset. The `type` syntax you used works only with variables.

All global macros that are defined are strings. The programmer and user can think they contain numbers if and only if their content can be used numerically.

A test of whether the input is numeric is to try something numeric, e.g.

```
capture di 1 + $smth1 

if _rc di "it is a string" 

else di "it is a number"
```

This is not quite fail-safe, as a string might contain the name of a numeric variable or scalar, in which case the operation should work.

A test of whether a global macro contains a string that can be interpreted as an integer is to check whether `floor($smth1) == $smth1` or equivalently that `ceil()` and `round()` return the input value.

There is no sense in which a global macro or its contents can be a `float` or `int`, except by trying whether such a variable would accept the contents as a value.

Stata's terminology here is that of many statistical programs in which a variable is a column in a dataset. It comes as a surprise to many of those who started with a mainstream programming language, as I did myself. More at https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html

The kind of input you are programming is now unusual in Stata.

Comment: Is there a way to add user input as a value in a dataset that is created when a program runs? An example is shown below:
di "Enter smth: " _request(smth1)
input str10 var1
"$smth1"
end

Once the above runs, one can create another program to use regexm to determine if the user input string contains a string, float or integer?

Comment: Sounds extraordinarily elaborate and roundabout to me.  You can take the user input and `generate` a string variable from it. If `destring` works, the content is numeric. But the best way to get user input is to write a program with options and get the user to input options.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Cox. The options' bit sounds useful to convert user input to numeric. Managed to find a workaround although yes, it is still a roundabout way - create a default dataset with one predefined string value and then circle back to replace that string value with user input macro, i.e. ''' replace val = "$smth1" ''' - that way, the user input macro can be converted into a string and added into the custom dataset and filtered with regexm by creating 3 variables that indicate 1 or 0 for integer, float or string.